# Creating a custom function in jquery results undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning how to create a custom function in jquery. I see on the internet on how to create a custom function and test it on my own. I have this code below as my testing but unfortunately my custom function is undefine unlike the `.repeat` function. I am planning to create here is is like the repeat function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log = function(text) {
    $('#console').append($('<div>').text(text));
  };

  $.fn.duplify = function(count) {
    return count;
    //return this.each(function() {
    //Do stuff
    //});
  };

  try {
    console.log('hello'.repeat(2));
    console.log('hello'.duplify(3));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: You're calling your jQuery function on a string, not a jQuery object. `repeat()` works because it's a method available on String objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you I got the idea on how to create it.